# Как сделать задержку парсинга на node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер, request, cheerio

суть вопроса: У меня есть скажем 12 000 страниц одного сайта, при обычном парсинге с помощью `request`
и `cheerio` через несколько страниц сайт падает с ошибкой.  Как мне при парсинге осуществить задержку и последовательный парсинг контента 12 000 страниц из файла?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Какая именно ошибка возникает?

Comment: @Sheridan ошибка на сайте которого хочу спарсить: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Comment: посмотрите на эту библиотеку: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-rate-limiter

Comment: а таймаут между ними поставить?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно отказаться от параллельной работы, либо как то её ограничить. Я бы использовал очереди с callback'ами. Для основы взял бы [вот этот код](https://gist.github.com/igorkulman/9110555)